# mousePressEvent doesnt work on child widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

So, I was trying to print the mouse position everytime I left-clicked but it only works outside the layout and I have no clue how to fix it. My GUI looks like this:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from untitled import Ui_Dialog


class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QMouseEvent):
        print(a0.pos())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is my untitled.py file

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Dialog)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mousePressEvent` event is invoked only if the widget is going to process that information, so if in the zone where you click there are other children widgets that event will not be received, so you only get the click where there is no other widget on top, so The solution in these cases is to listen to the event through `eventFilter`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from untitled import Ui_Dialog


class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        for w in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget)+[self]:
            w.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                print(obj, "global pos:", event.globalPos(), 
                            "local pos", event.pos(),
                            "position with respect to self",
                            self.mapFromGlobal(obj.mapToGlobal(event.pos())))
        return super(AppWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Lindau no, in SO it suffices to mark a response as correct so that the OP (the one who asks) indicates that he has solved his problem, please check the [tour] so that you know more SO rules.

Comment: Ah, okay! I will check out the tour. Thanks for all the help!